# How do I make an object flicker at specific times?

Tags: animation

I want to make an specific object flicker at specific times. Can I do this by using a driver? If not how?

E.g. I am creating the word "earth". If I start the animation in x time I need to make the 1st letter glow in exactly x+9 seconds, then the 2nd letter should glow in x+9+9 seconds.

Comment: have you tried with the modifiers of the Graph Editor? You give 2 keyframes to your Emission shader, then go in the Graph Editor, press N > Modifiers, create a Noise, play with the parameters, and click on Restrict Frame Range to make the effect begin and end whenever you want?

Comment: I will try that. .. looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let say you've created your object. Give it an *Emission* shader, create at least 1 keyframe at frame 1 with a value of 1 for example.

[image]

Open the *Graph Editor* (to switch from the *Dope Sheet* just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>). Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the right panel, click on the *Modifiers* tab and create a *Noise* modifier. Play with the parameters (*Scale, Strength*...). If you want the modifier to happen at a precise frame click on the *Restrict Frame Range* and set the *Start* and *End* values.

[image]